# Error con try catch

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo programando, y es la primera vez que ocupo el try catch en c++ ¿alguien me podria explicar por que no funciona mi codigo?
Ocupo DevC++ con el compilador GCC4.9
Lo que busco es verificar que lo que entra es un número, si lo que entra no es un numero arrojar la excepción y que se pueda volver a ingresar el número, ya leí la documentación de printf, pero no hay ninguna función como .fail() o algo parecido.

```
try 
    { 
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if(x==NULL)
        {
            throw int(x);
        }
    }
    catch ( int  x)
    {
        printf("\nEso no es un numero...\n");
        printf("intentalo de nuevo\n");
        goto principio;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué comportamiento esperabas?

Comment: ¿tu variable x la estas inicializando de esta forma: int x=NULL;?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Quisiera poder hacer que se arrojara la excepcion si lo que entra no es un numero. No sé cómo hacer esta verificación

Answer (score 4):

Tu código tiene muchos fallos, a muchos niveles; el resultado que buscas no tiene mucho que ver con lo que realmente estás haciendo. Voy a intentar señalar los fallos por orden:

#### [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) es un mecanismo de lectura de datos de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Para la lectura de datos desde consola en C++ se usa una instancia de flujo de entrada de datos llamada [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin), la función que has usado pertenece a C y no debe ser usada ya que es propensa a errores al carecer de seguridad de tipos y comprobaciones en tiempo de compilación. Para leer un entero (`int`) mediante el flujo de entrada de datos de C++ deberías escribir lo siguiente:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
```

Esto en cuanto a lo que **deberías** hacer, en cuanto a hacer funcionar lo que has hecho y **no deberías estar haciendo**, basta con consultar el funcionamiento de `scanf`:

#### Valor de retorno de `scanf`.

La función `scanf` tiene un valor de retorno, este retorno es la cantidad de parámetros de entrada que se hayan podido leer, así que si estás leyendo sobre `x` y la lectura (`scanf("%d",&x);`) devuelve cero, significa que no leíste nada.

#### Si `x` es puntero: no es número, si `x` es número: no es puntero.

La variable `x` la estás leyendo como un número, eso significa el `"%d"` que usas en `scanf`:

```
scanf("%d",&x);
//    ^^^^ <--- Leer un número.
```

Pero después compruebas si has leído un puntero nulo, que es lo que representa la macro `NULL`:

```
if(x==NULL)
//    ^^^^ <--- ¿Es 'x' igual a PUNTERO NULO?
```

Resulta que la macro [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL) es el valor `0` (o el valor `0` convertido a puntero a `void`) por lo que si `x` fuese un entero (`int`) podría compararse contra `NULL`, para evitar esta comparación que no tiene sentido, deberías usar el literal de puntero nulo: [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr):

```
if (x == nullptr)
```

De esta manera, si `x` no es un puntero, el programa no compilará.

#### No lances (`throw`) valores, lanza excepciones.

Si tu código se ha encontrado con una excepción, debes lanzar una excepción que describa el problema, lanzar un número no aporta ninguna información del fallo. Echa un vistazo a las excepciones de [`<exception>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/exception), parece que en tu caso [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) podría ser un buen candidato:

```
throw std::logic_error{"Eso no es un numero"};
```

O crea tu propia excepción:

```
struct no_es_un_numero : std::logic_error {
    using logic_error::logic_error;
};

…
…

throw no_es_un_numero{"Eso no es un numero"};
```

#### Mejor aún, no lances excepciones para cosas que no son excepcionales.

Las excepciones son un mecanismo de control de errores, están pensadas para capturar errores irrecuperables y poder finalizar el proceso de manera segura. **Las excepciones no son un mecanismo de control de flujo del programa**.

No debes hacer que el flujo normal de tu programa dependa de excepciones: las excepciones son para casos excepcionales, no para casos que forman parte de la lógica del programa.

Pero si vas a usar excepciones:

#### Captura (`catch`) las excepciones como referencia constante.

Si capturas excepciones, hazlo como referencia constante.

```
try
{
    …
}
catch (const std::logic_error &e)
{
    …
}
```

Así evitarás copiar el objeto excepción en toda la cadena de captura.

#### No uses `goto`.

No uses `goto`, cuando creas que tu código puede salir beneficiado por usar `goto`, vuelve a pensarlo porque te estarás equivocando.

---

Con todo lo dicho, tu código seguramente estará fallando porque al leer un número sobre `x` el número que pasas **nunca** es `0` por lo que **nunca** se cumple la condición para lanzar la excepción; pero ese es el menor de tus problemas porque prácticamente tienes un fallo en cada una de las líneas de tu programa.